# Angular 2 Testing: find, fill up and submit a form

Tags: forms, angular, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular2 frontend with few components and I want to test a form contained in the formular.componet, this form is searching for an address on gmap and returning all the locations of agencies around that location, here is the ts file:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ags-form',
  templateUrl: 'formular.component.html'
})
export class FormularComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  public searchName: string = '';
  public searchAddress: string = '';
  private searchAddendum: string = '';
  private searchDivision: string = '';
  private searchRadius: string = '';
  private autocompletePosition: any;
  private currentPosition: any;
…
  // configuration
  public configuration: Configuration;

  @ViewChild("dom_address_input") domAddressInput: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("dom_localizeButton") localizeButton: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(FormularAutocompleteComponent) autocompleteComponent: FormularAutocompleteComponent;

  private place_changed_fire: boolean = false;


  // autocompletion
  public suggestionList: string[] = [];
  private inputTimer: Timer;
  public autocompleteSelectedIndex: number = -1;
  public visibleAutoCompleteSuggestList: string = 'hide-class';
  public elementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone, private agencySearchService: AgencySearchService, private configurationService: ConfigurationService, private eventBusService: EventBusService, private notificationService: NotificationService, private myElement: ElementRef, private historyService: HistoryService) {
    this.configuration = configurationService.getConfiguration();
    this.elementRef = myElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // get division, addendum and radius
    let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    this.searchAddress = params.get('address') || '';
    this.searchName = params.get('name') || '';
    this.searchDivision = params.get('division') || '';
    this.searchAddendum = params.get('addendum') || '';
    this.searchRadius = params.get('radius') || '';

    if (this.searchDivision) {
      console.log("DIVSION: " + this.searchDivision);
      this.agencySearchService.sortMode = SortOptionEnum.RANKING;
    }

    if (this.searchAddress != '' || this.searchName != '') {
      this.submitSearchAction(true);
    }

    //load Places Autocomplete
    let options: any = {
      types: ['geocode'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'de'}
    };
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new window['google'].maps.places.Autocomplete(this.domAddressInput.nativeElement, options);

      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          let place: any = autocomplete.getPlace();
          place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          //verify result
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          } else {
            this.place_changed_fire = true;
            this.autocompletePosition = {
              lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
              lon: place.geometry.location.lng(),
              name: this.searchAddress
            };
            this.submitSearchAction(true);
          }

        });
      });
    });


  search(): void {
    this.submitSearchAction(true);
  }
…
}
```

This is the related htm file (form)

```
<form class="agency-search-form form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="location-container">
        <input id="address_input" type="text" class="gmap-street form-control" [ngClass]="errorAddressClass" (keyup)="keyupSearchAddress($event)"
               name="address_input"
               placeholder="Straße, PLZ oder Ort" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" [(ngModel)]="searchAddress" #dom_address_input>
        <a href="#" class="localization disabled" (click)="clickLocalizeButton()" #dom_localizeButton></a>
        <span class="azfs icon-info-clickable green iconInfoAddress" [ngClass]="infoIconAddressClass"
              (click)="clickIconInfoAddress()"><div
          class="azfs has-information-arrow infoAddressArrow"
          [ngClass]="visibleInfoAddressClass"></div></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row autocompleteAnchor">
      <form-autocomplete [(searchName)] ="searchName" (startSearch)="submitSearchAction(true)" (setButtonState)="setSearchButtonState($event)"></form-autocomplete>
      <input id="name_input" name="name_input" type="text" class="gmap-name form-control" [ngClass]="errorNameClass"
             placeholder="Name der Agentur" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" [(ngModel)]="searchName"  (keyup)="keyupSearch($event)">
      <span class="azfs icon-info-clickable green iconInfoName" [ngClass]="infoIconNameClass"
            (click)="clickIconInfoName()"><div
        class="azfs has-information-arrow infoNameArrow" [ngClass]="visibleInfoNameClass"></div></span>
    </div>



    <button type="button" class="agency-search-submit button hero" tabindex="3" (click)="search()" [disabled]="disabledSearchButton">Suchen</button>
  </form>
```

What I want to do is to fill up the form, submit and check for the response,

so how do I:

> 1)    Find the form and fill it up on the test method
>
> 2)    How do I submit the form and send the event
>
> 3)    How do I get the response from the eventbus
>
> 4)    On Test 1 when I set formularInstance.searchAddress and I
>   immediately log it after, it results undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Here the tests file for this component:

```
import {async,TestBed,ComponentFixture,ComponentFixtureAutoDetect} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {AgmCoreModule} from "@agm/core";
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {ConfigurationService} from "../shared/services/configuration.service";
import {AgencySearchService} from "../shared/services/agency-search.service";
import {EventBusService} from "../shared/services/event-bus.service";
import {HistoryService} from "../shared/services/history.service";
import {NotificationService} from "../shared/services/notification-service";

import {FormularComponent} from '../formular.component';


describe('Formular', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormularComponent>;
  let formularInstance: FormularComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AgmCoreModule.forRoot(),HttpModule],
      declarations: [
        FormularComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        ConfigurationService,
        AgencySearchService,
        EventBusService,
        HistoryService,
        NotificationService,
        { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents().catch(error => console.error(error));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormularComponent);
    formularInstance = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));


  // Test 1
  it('should create a `Form`', () => {
    formularInstance.searchAddress = 'Munich';
    console.log('Search Address before: '+formularInstance.searchAddress);
    formularInstance.ngOnInit();
    console.log('Search Address after: '+formularInstance.searchAddress);
    console.log('Info Message: '+formularInstance.infoMessage);
    console.log('Error Message: '+formularInstance.errorMessage);
  });

  // Test 2
  it('Submit a `Form` call', () => {
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#input_address'));
    input.nativeElement.value = 'München';

    input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('form'));

  });

});
```

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/guide/testing ?

Comment: Yes man, some basic test of mine are working thanks to that document, hovewer when it comes to test complexes components I have no idea where to start...

Comment: I think we should separate your problem and solve everything one by one

Comment: Im with you man!

Comment: Find the form and fill it up on the test method. Do you want to fill the field and emulate button click or do you want to just provide some model and call some method and assert that needed things will be done?

Comment: fill fields and push button, than look at the event

Comment: So how just need to find elements by selector. Set values. Then find button same way and push it. Then check event was emmited. What problems do you have there? If I remember correctly there are some examples in testing guide.

Comment: its alway popping out this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined; beside thath im not shure im correctly catching the event

Comment: On what instruction?

Comment: Also it is strange how you get route parameters. Angular have api for that

Comment: Exactly on this test:   // Test 5
  it('Set the input box of `Form`', () => {
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const inputHtmlElement = input.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    inputHtmlElement.value = 'München, Deutschland';
    console.log('searchAddress: '+formularInstance.searchAddress);
    inputHtmlElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  });

Comment: But there is no test5 in your question.

Comment: I highly recommend **you** to separate this into several posts. And solve your problems 1 by 1. This is too broad. As you see it is hard to help you.